# Stop a Process that contains example and stop it

Tags: powershell

The following script have to automaticly stop all `example*` processes but not that ones which are in an .txt File called no_stop.txt:

```
    $no = get-content no_stop.txt;
$yes = get-process example* | Select-Object name >> text2.txt;

if($no)
{
for($i1=0; $i1 -le $no.length; $i1++)
{
    for($i2=0; $i2 -le $yes.length;$i2++)
    {
        if($no[$i1] -eq $yes[$i2])
        {
            $yes[$i2]='';

        }
        if($yes[$i2] -eq 'Name' >> text2.txt)
        {
            $yes[$i2]='';
        }
        if($yes[$i2] -eq '-' >> text2.txt)
        {
            $yes[$i2]='';
        }
    }
}
}

for($i1=0; $i1 -le $yes.length;$i1++)
{
if($yes[$i1])
{
        $yes[$i1] = $yes[$i1] -replace '\s','' >>test.txt;
        Stop-Process $yes[$i1] -Force >>test.txt;
}
}
$yes >> test.txt;
```

Somehow this doesn`t work, can you explain me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$no = @(Get-Content C:\File\Path\no_start.txt) -join '|'
Get-Service example* | ?{$_.Name -notmatch $no} | Start-Service -PassThru`

That also works fine and it can read multiply lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this a lot:

```
$no = get-content no_stop.txt;
Get-Process example* | Where { $no -notcontains $_.Name } | kill -Force
```

Comment: You should try to full qualify the pass of no_stop.txt. To get the error, start PowerShell_ISE, open your script and hit F5...

Comment: Then just execute the script from powershell like: `& "path_to_your_script.ps1"`

Comment: Please share the content of no_stop.txt with us.

Comment: Well, due to your PowerShell version, you have to put that into curly brackets and use `-notcontains` instead of `-notin`. I updated my answer. Please try again.

Comment: Im sure you will figure that one out. Please consider accept the answer if it was helpfull

Comment: I realised an serious Problem, if   no_stop.txt contains more than 1 Process it will kill all Processes include that from no_stop.txt....

Comment: Oh yes sure, because I changed the parameter I had to switch them as well. I updated my answer.

Comment: I have two lines in my no_stop.txt and it also closes the second one...